# Enable VPF libraries (hard) with arm-gcc

Tags: gcc, arm

I'm trying to build an application that links a library that is built with `VFP`. I have added the flags `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard` to my `arm-gcc` command, but it complains about that the standard C library (`libm.a` and the like) is not built using `VFP`.

I have noticed that in my `arm-gcc` toolchain directory, in `lib`, there is a folder called `hard` which is supposed to contain the `arm` standard C libraries built with `VFP`.

How can I make this library folder the standard one for the `arm` toolchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had some missing flags. Below I list all of them:

`-mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard`